# How has it happen, that Soviet Union, after the win in WW2 did not took German technologies?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, soviet-union

Germany, in the 40-x was a one of most technological advanced state in the world. Following big concerns had created it's industry: VW, Mercedes(created in  1926, Benz & Daimler), Siemens(in 1847), particularly Ford, chemical concerns, omg, what else Germany had there and none of this technologies were assimilated by Soviet Union?

Comment: Isn't Ford an American company?

Comment: Good question. They took nuclear expertise. It stands to reason they'd take other technology too.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that the Soviet Union failed to assimilate German technology?  Is that statement true?

Comment: Ford had branches there, as you may know. 
Interesting proof: in the Nuremberg Trial was said a bit that the "americans" (but read- private companies) have armed Germany (!).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the factual premise if wrong.

Comment: You might ask yourself how two countries with very little rocketry experience (the US and USSR) ended up pointing thousands of ICBMs towards each other not all that long after the war.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_space_program#The_Germans

Comment: This question is so poorly written that I'm honestly shocked anyone was even able to answer it.

Comment: The premise of the question is wrong. What should have been asked instead is how much technology the Soviet Union collected as spoils of war. (I'm not saying the Soviet Union was evil. Spoils of war are a fact of life. The US, British, and French also collected spoils of war.) The Soviets sent teams of trophy hunters into Germany to collect technological trophies, particularly nuclear, space, and aircraft technology.

Comment: Because Van Bruan went out of his way to select which side he would end up on.

Answer (score 6):

"Why is the Moon made of Green cheese ?" This is the same type of question.
Soviet Union did take everything it could from Germany. Including whole factories, machine tools, documentation, and specialists. (Most of the specialists were released and returned in 1950s). On a very large scale.

As a child I lived in Soviet Union and had some opportunities to visit several factories. This was
in 1960-70th.  Most of the machinery I've seen there was German made and dated 1930th. It was hopelessly obsolete at the time when I saw it, of course. Whole new industries started in Soviet Union based on the war booty. For example sometimes famous Soviet optics (photo cameras, binoculars etc.) Till the very end of Soviet Union this was produced with German machinery, by German technology. Not to mention the rocket science and space technology. 
Standard lab equipment (like oscillographs) just did not exist in Soviet Union before 1945, except possibly some purely working experimental samples.

Comment: Thanks, i did not knew about  taken 'specialists' or (why  famous?) 'Soviet optics' or 'oscillographs'. 
I  do know, just from books and media, about 30-x machine-tools, running in 80-x, but exactly that shows **no assimilation**, because **learning** the technology means (for me) also lean to **develop** it.